# ffmpeg couldn't process files uploaded via ajax C#

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

I've tried to extract one part from a mp4 file using ffmpeg but it returns an empty file, could you guys please help to check on this?really drive me mad...a big thanks on advance!

1.I tried to set the output file to another file(not self replace) and it works.
2.I tried to post back the filename to client by ajax, video couldn't been load but it can play on server(the ffmpeg generated file is not corrupted)
3.I closed the localhost and re-launch it, the mp4 file could be loaded properly.

--question
1.is the file uploaded to server been occupied?(I tried to delete it, it's workable, and I already called dispose after generated the original file)

2.why I restart localhost, it becomes workable??what have been done during close localhost??

```
for C# code to save file,please refer to below
HttpPostedFileWrapper video---param
string extension = new FileInfo(video.FileName).Extension;
string videoId = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
string filePath =HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/video/" + videoId + extension);
var videoFile = File.Create(filePath);
video.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
video.InputStream.CopyTo(videoFile);
videoFile.Close();
videoFile.Dispose();
```

for ffmpeg please refer to below

```
E:\tools\ticon\ffmpeg-20180619-a990184-win64-static\bin>ffmpeg -ss 1.67 -t 4.10 -i E:\MyMVCProj\MyMVCProj\MyMVCProj\video\7802334805.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy E:\MyMVCProj\MyMVCProj\MyMVCProj\video\7802334805.mp4 -y
ffmpeg version N-91330-ga990184007 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 7.3.0 (GCC)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
libavutil      56. 18.102 / 56. 18.102
libavcodec     58. 20.103 / 58. 20.103
libavformat    58. 17.100 / 58. 17.100
libavdevice    58.  4.101 / 58.  4.101
libavfilter     7. 25.100 /  7. 25.100
libswscale      5.  2.100 /  5.  2.100
libswresample   3.  2.100 /  3.  2.100
libpostproc    55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from      
'E:\MyMVCProj\MyMVCProj\MyMVCProj\video\7802334805.mp4':
Metadata:
major_brand     : mp42
minor_version   : 1
compatible_brands: mp41mp42isom
creation_time   : 2018-06-21T11:26:01.000000Z
Duration: 00:00:09.80, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1284 kb/s
Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 62 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2018-06-21T11:26:01.000000Z
  handler_name    : Core Media Audio
 Stream #0:1(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/bt709/bt709, progressive), 960x540, 1216 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc (default)

Metadata:
    rotate          : 90
    creation_time   : 2018-06-21T11:26:01.000000Z
    handler_name    : Core Media Video
  Side data:
  displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
Output #0, mp4, to 'E:\MyMVCProj\MyMVCProj\MyMVCProj\video\7802334805.mp4':
Metadata:
major_brand     : mp42
minor_version   : 1
compatible_brands: mp41mp42isom
encoder         : Lavf58.17.100
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/bt709/bt709, progressive), 960x540, q=2-31, 1216 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 19200 tbn, 600 tbc (default)
Metadata:
  rotate          : 90
  creation_time   : 2018-06-21T11:26:01.000000Z
  handler_name    : Core Media Video
Side data:
  displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 62 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2018-06-21T11:26:01.000000Z
  handler_name    : Core Media Audio
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (copy)
Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x
 video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

Comment: Looks like the file is locked, probably your file writting c# code is not freeing its resouces. Improve your question adding  the relevant c# code.

Comment: BTW, " _I_ _already_ _called_ _Dispose_ "... Woul like to have a look at that code, there are probably easier ways to write files, for example https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Looks like `video.InputStream` does also implement `IDisposable`. You are neither closing it after working with it nor disposing it.

Comment: I'll have a try,thanks!

Comment: I tried to call dispose func for that and still a 0KB file returned..maybe the file is still in using by some thread..

Answer (score 0):

[resolved] ffmpeg latest version must have some fatal bug in it, I downgraded it to previous version and it worked.